# How does Salesforce run apex tests in parallel?

Tags: apex, unit-test

Does anyone know how exactly Salesforce runs apex tests in parallel? How many tests can be run in parallel at any given time? For example, we have 1000 apex tests and when we run them all via CLI command `sfdx force:apex:test:run`. Does it mean that these tests start executing all at once (given that the `Disable Parallel Apex Testing` option is set to FALSE)?

It's not clear from the documentation.

Comment: You can observe the behaviour because your test execution submission can be monitored through the Setup UI > Custom Code > Apex Test Execution. You'll see animation of the tests that are running together and those that are queued. Through this you can see that only a hand-full of test classes run at the same time. The specific number, I've never checked, and the ordering of executions seems somewhat random, as an observer. I've not spotted a specific pattern.

Answer (score -2):

1. The tests will be executed in parallel mode since 'Disable Parallel Apex Testing' is set to false
2. The Apex Test Will be executed randomly
3. Open Dev Console and then run the command
4. So a temporary test suite will be created with all the apex test class names and their results will be displayed
5. Else you can go to **Setup** and view the test results in **Apex Test Execution** page